# Redshift - Filter out values without comma in row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a column that has values with commas (,). I am trying to filter out rows that do not have a comma.

Given below is a sample view of my dataset

```
id,name,product_list
1,kevin,prod_a
2,scott,prod_b,prod_c
3,tim,prod_a
4,julie,prod_a,prod_e
```

I am expecting the SQL to return only ids (1,3) as they do not have a comma in ***product_list*** column. Could anyone help me on how could I filter the above data set.

I am using Redshift DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways of doing it and one is already suggested, then another could be:

```
select * from test where len(product_list)-len(REPLACE(product_list,',',''))<1;
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use like operator

```
select * from table1 where product_list NOT LIKE '%,%'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a081d/1

```
id  name    productlist
1   kevin   prod_a
3   tim     prod_a
```

Comment: @dark horse does it helps ?